# Cannot get PayPal sandbox account to link to third party permissions

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

My goal is to create a business PayPal sandbox account which has the account type `Business Pro` and which allows me to grant access to third party APIs.

Currently there are two ways of creating sandbox accounts in PayPal. The first method involves creating an account from the developer dashboard and linking that account to the PayPal dev account via the link provided on the Sandbox Accounts page. However, creating an account this way does not allow me to link third party APIs. When I log into the sandbox account and click the link to update `Api Access` it gives a browser error of "Too many redirects".

The second way of creating a sandbox account involves going to [sandbox.paypal.com](http://sandbox.paypal.com) and signing up a Business account on there. I am then able to link this sandbox account to the PayPal dev account from, again the link provided in the dev dashboard. Creating a sandbox account this way also allows me bypass the browser error and link third party APIs. However, it doesn't allow me to upgrade that sandbox account to Business Pro, and gives me the following error: `Something went wrong. PayPal Payments Pro could not be enabled. Try again.`

Is there any way I can create a sandbox account which is able to link to third party APIs and be a Business Pro type?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else that might have this problem, I had to create a ticket here: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask and ask them the question of why it wasn't linking. They had to change my account type to a new one that they were/are developing.

Comment: Clarificatio required